# How to find a certain string/name in a txt file?

Tags: python, random, generator, txt

So im making a name generator/finder, So for the find command i want to find that name in the txt file with the line number! So how do i find the name with the line number?

```
line = 0

names = open(r"names.txt", "r")
name1 = names.readlines()

uname = input("Please enter the name you want to find: ")
for name in name1:
  try:
    print(name)
    print(line)
    if name == uname:
      print(f"Found name: {name} \nLine No. {line + 1}")
    else:
      line = line + 1
  except:
    print("Unable to process")
```

But it seems to not work except if you write the last name in file it works. So could give any help?

EDIT: Ive found a way so you can reply if you want to for further people running into the problem!

Comment: The output of `readlines()` includes the newline character at the end of each line.  So you need to strip that off, otherwise you're comparing `"Steve"` to `"Steve\n"`, which aren't equal.

Comment: Don't use a bare `except`. Always use it with the error you want to catch. What kind of error would you expect in your code anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open("names.txt", "r") as f:
    file_contents = names.read().splitlines()

uname = input("Please enter the name you want to find: ")

for line, row in enumerate(file_contents):
    if uname in row:
        print('Name "{0}" found in line {1}'.format(uname, line))
```

Comment: I like the `with` statement and `enumerate` but using `in` for the comparison isn't the best idea. If I want to search "Carl" but there's no "Carl" in the file but "Carlos" the program will still tell me it found "Carl".

Comment: Good point, I suppose if lines only contain names then you can use `==`, otherwise a more clever way is needed (e.g. if the line contains "Carlosnumber1234" you can't easily search for "Carl").

Answer (score 0):

Yo

```
if "namefilled" in name :
```

print("found it")

Answer (score 0):

You can use pathlib if you have Python 3.4+.  Pretty handy library.

Also, context management is useful.

```
# Using pathlib
from pathlib import Path

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html?highlight=fnmatch#module-fnmatch
import fnmatch

# Create Path() instance with path to text file (can be reference)
txt_file = Path(r"names.txt")

# Gather input
uname = input("Please enter the name you want to find: ")

# Set initial line variable
line = 0

find_all = False

# Use context maangement to auto-close file once complete.
with txt_file.open() as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # If python 3.8, you can use assignment operator (:=)
        if match_list := fnmatch.filter(line, uname) is not None: # Doe not match substring.
        
            number_of_names = len(match_list)

            name_index = [i for i, element in enumerate(line.split()) for word in match_list if word == element]

            print(f"""
            {number_of_names} name{"s" if number_of_names > 0 else ""} found on line {line} at position {name_index}.
            """.strip())

    line += 1
```

## Edited to include fnmatch per some other comments in this thread about matching the full string vs. a substring.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import re

search_name = input("Enter the name to find: ")

with open("names.txt", "r") as f:
    for line, row in enumerate(f.read().splitlines()):
        if re.findall('\\b'+search_name+'\\b', row, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            print('Name "{0}" found in line {1}'.format(search_name, line))
```

You can remove the `flags=re.IGNORECASE` flag in case you want the seaarch to be case-sensetive.

Comment: I changed a bit stuff and it worked! Thanks for the help!